# How to save associated models in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have five models and their respective tables are

```
Member:id,fname,lname
Student:id,member_id(foreign key references member table id),order_id (references order table id)
Contact:id,member_contact_id(foreign key references Member id)
Address:id,city,state
Order:id,student_id(foreign key references student id),contact_id( foreign references contact id),address_id(foreign key references address id
```

and i established relation in models also.

when i do

```
$this->Order->saveAll($this->session->read())
```

only contact and address and in order contact_id and address_id is saving but the member and student is not saving.

please give me the solution to save all the models at on shot.

Comment: If you don't post your model code, we can only guess at the problem. I realise that there may be quite a bit of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cake only does 2 level deep association saves with saveAll (or multi rows of the same model)

you will need to roll your own save with a few foreach loops or just saving the various parts of the data.

eg: you use saveAll to save the contact and address and then get the id's. manually set the ids of the fk in the other data and then call a bunch of saves for the remaining data.

Comment: in Cake 2.1+, add the parameter 'deep' => TRUE to save deeper than two levels.